# What's the procedure when a question is not answerable (yet)?

Tags: discussion, scope

Ok not to be intentional subjective but what do I do? In my question [In the Doctor Who universe, who is the mysterious lady who carries the blue journal?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/in-the-doctor-who-universe-who-is-the-mysterious-lady-who-carries-the-blue-journ) I find that I'm told an answer is not yet available and that **spoiler** we might know soon.

What do I do on this case, keep the question open ended until we know the answer (wait for the broadcast of it) or accept the unknown answer as a solution? I know someone will be bound to ask this question later, when a real answer is available. So what is the general way of handling such instances?

I guess this is bound to happen every so often in plot like questions on an ongoing canon or universe. Do we have a "known way" to handle these questions or do we need one? Like mark questions "Unanswerable" until its reopened by request... I don't know.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31/where-can-i-find-a-full-copy-of-philip-k-dicks-exegesis This is an example of one of these.

Comment: This question/answer set largely conflict with our (later and more highly upvoted) "[Future Works Policy"](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based)

Comment: @Valorum Indeed. Perhaps this older question should be closed as a duplicate of the current policy?

Comment: @RandAl'Thor - I'd flag it as such, except that my vote is binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, we know that there will eventually be an answer.  So, leave it open until we get an answer.  For cases where, for example, the author died without revealing the solution to a mystery, then the correct answer would be 'we don't know'.

Comment: Thank you! I suspected as much, just wanted to be sure...

Comment: Preferably "We Don't Know - However these are the N theories as to..."

Comment: Keep in mind that where the current answer is "nobody knows", another answer can always be added to the page and marked the correct answer if the answer becomes known later on.